# How to communicate between micro front end applications angular

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation, nx-angular

I have 3 independent angular application running using MFE architecture. I want to communicate each other . What is the best approach to communicate between each other other than using local storage.

All these apps are running and managed by different repositories and deployed independently

I have tried different approach like local storage, library etc. but since all the applications are independently deployed its not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

so far I have found

```
dispatchEventFromHostFn() {
const customEvent = new CustomEvent("testEventFromHost", { detail: { data: "testEventFromHost" } });
dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

Then listen it in the remote app

```
 // observable, so we can unsubscribe
fromEvent(window, "testEventFromHost").subscribe((res) => {
  console.log("!!fromEvent testEventFromHost", res);
});
```